# How do you validate request parameters in WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

how do you validate request parameters in WebFlux?

Any suggestions to make this code as beautiful and short as in case of usage of JSR 303 and RestControllers?

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getStatistic(ServerRequest request) {
    Integer pageSize = request.queryParam(Constants.SIZE_PARAM)
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .filter(x -> x.compareTo(Constants.MAX_PAGE_SIZE) <= 0)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("..."));
    // ...

}
```

Comment: I assume you had (at)Valid in the method signatures of classes which were annotated with (at)RestController. I didn't find a solution to do the same with handler classes in WebFlux. Therefore, I added @Validated to my (at)Service classes, and (at)Valid to the according methods.

Comment: Yes, it can be a solution. I just don't want to mix parameters validation with business logic.